# Does infinite mass exist?

Tags: special-relativity, mass, mass-energy, singularities

So when I search up if infinite mass exists, google provides me with a source that states infinite relativistic mass does exist at the speed of light which is why it is impossible to ever reach to speed of light because an infinite mass requires infinite energy. I also hear a lot of other people say infinite mass doesn't exist at all.

Comment: Using what you have said, infinite mass is not obtainable. I think your answer is in your question. (Ignoring that the idea of relativistic mass is not widely used anymore)

Comment: So basically infinite mass doesn't exist because a physical object can't ever reach it.

Comment: If you want to use that framework yes. The answer already given explains everything much better though.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of relativistic mass is an out-of-date interpretation of special relativity. You can find it in many textbooks, including the (justly) celebrated Feynman Lectures. But Einstein himself advised against it:

"It is not good to introduce the concept of the mass $M = m/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$ of a moving body for which no clear definition can be given. It is better to introduce no other mass concept than the ’rest mass’ $m$. Instead of introducing $M$ it is better to mention the expression for the momentum and energy of a body in motion."

The relativistic expression for the energy of a particle is

$$ E = \frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}},$$

where $m$ is the rest mass and $v$ is the speed of the particle. As the speed approaches $c$, $E$ tends to infinity. You could focus on the $m/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$ part of the expression and say that quantity is tending to infinity, and then argue that you can't accelerate a thing with infinite mass. That makes a certain amount of sense, but it also implies that $m/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$ has some physically meaningful interpretation for $v \lt c$ that would not causes problems in the internal logic of the theory. But this isn't the case. Probably the most serious problem is that we have now identified "mass" as determining the 0-component of the energy-momentum 4-vector, but it is already identified with the magnitude of that 4-vector, through

$$E^2 - \left(pc^2\right) = \left(mc^2\right)^2.$$

On the other hand, as a particle speeds up, the increase in energy must come from the work done on the particle by the net force that is changing its speed. To reach a speed $c$ requires infinite work, meaning either an infinite force applied over a finite distance, or a finite force applied over an infinite distance. Infinite work, force, and distance are meaningful concepts in at least an abstract sense, but clearly not physically realizable. So we can reach the conclusion that it is impossible to accelerate a particle to $v = c$ without having to say anything about relativistic mass.